# How to best use connection pooling in SQLAlchemy for PgBouncer transaction-level pooling?

Tags: python, postgresql

Using SQLAlchemy to query a PostgreSQL database behind PgBouncer, using transaction-level pooling.

What is the best pattern to use for this kind of set up?  Should I have one-engine-per-process, using a `ConnectionPool`, or should I create an engine per-request, and use `NullPool` for each one of them?  Is there a different pattern altogether that I should be using?

Thanks very much!  Let me know if more information is needed and I'll update ASAP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

with PGBouncer, you'd probably want to just stick with NullPool.  In that case you may be able to share a single Engine across subprocesses since no socket connections will be carried over the subprocess boundary.  But you can't share anything referring to a Connection object, like a Session with an active transaction, over this boundary.    You definitely wouldn't want to do "engine-per-request" though, an Engine is an expensive object that accumulates a lot of information about a particular database URL the first time it sees it.

Answer (score 10):

**Set the Application Name**

If you expect to be running many processes you need to know where they are
connecting from. PGBouncer will make this invisible to `pg_stat_activity`. Solve
this by carefully setting the `application_name` with the information you'll
need:

```
# Sets the application name for this connection in the form of
#   application-name:user@host
prog = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]) or 'desjob'
username = pwd.getpwuid (os.getuid ()).pw_name
hostname = socket.gethostname().split(".")[0]·
args.setdefault('connect_args', {'application_name': "%s:%s@%s" %
    (prog, username, hostname)})
args.setdefault('isolation_level', "AUTOCOMMIT")
engine = create_engine(url, **args)
```

**Prefer Sessions**

Use Sessions since requests from an Engine object can spawn and hold on to
multiple connections. Connecting to Postgres is not very expensive, with
PGBouncer it's even less so. I would always use `NullPool` so that the only
connections you will see in Postgres are the connections that are actually being
used.

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import Pool, NullPool
engine = create_engine(uri, poolclass=NullPool)
```

**Eliminate Idle Transactions**

If your intent is to use PGBouncer to scale then it is imperative that you avoid
leaving transactions stuck open. To do this you need to turn `autocommit` **on**. This is not simple with SQLAlchemy...there are three places
where something called "autocommit" can be set:

*psycopg2 autocommit*

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(uri)
conn.autocommit = True
```

Presumed to be unsafe unsafe because SQLAlchemy needs to know what's happening underneath.

*Session autocommit*

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)
session = Session()
```

This requires careful, explicit handing:

```
session.begin()
session.execute(...)
session.rollback()
```

Function calling and exception handing is exceedingly difficult because
`begin()` and `commit()` cannot be nested:

```
def A():
  session.begin()
  ...
  session.rollback()

def B():
  session.begin()
  try:
      A() # error, already open
```

In this mode psycopg2 `autocommit` appears to be `False` (the default)

*Engine autocommit*

Setting the Engine isolation mode to `"AUTOCOMMIT"` when creating the engine
establishes new default behavior that may not require changes
to existing code.

```
engine = create_engine(uri, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
```

In this mode psycopg2 `autocommit` appears to be `True`

The major problem here is that the only way to guarantee that
a block of code is wrapped in a transaction is to emit the statements manually:

```
session.execute("BEGIN")
#...
session.execute("COMMIT")
```

Comment: God, I'm so happy I found this information! It literally saved me! Thank you so much for such an informative and comprehensive answer! 
I use FastAPI, SQLAlchemy (in async mode), PgBouncer and PostgreSQL. I had a problem with leaking database connections. it took me a long time to figure out what the issue was and how to fix it. everything looked ok in the code, but the graphana showed a steady trend of constantly increasing number of connections to the database.

Comment: Our devops were complaining, i was uncomfortable. after i asked them to show info about connections of my service in PgBouncer, i saw that all of them in idlie status, your information gave me an understanding why and how to fix it. 
thank you so much again!

Comment: @eradman  What do you think is the most idiomatic way to do it in sqlalchemy 2.0 with no autocommit?

Comment: Time will tell what pitfalls there are to working with sqlalchemy 2.0. It will make my answer above obsolete. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html

Comment: Here is some very important information about leaky connections and errors you may get when working with SQLA + FastAPI: https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/978